# Magento Commerce 2.3 Quick order link for logged in customers only

Tags: magento2.3, customer, magento2-b2b

By default the Quick order functionality of the **B2B module** is available for both logged in users as well as for guest users.
What can I do to **hide it from guest users** and make it available/visible for logged in users only? Basically It would even be sufficient to **hide the Quick Order link** in the top link section.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by checking if the customer is logged in a Custom Block that overrides
`Magento_QuickOrder/Block/Link` using the di.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Please add as below in xml file

```
<customer_logged_in>
        <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Quick Order</label><url helper="Your/quickOrderUrl"/><title>Log Out</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
        </reference>
    </customer_logged_in>
```

Comment: Thanks but in M2 the customer_logged_in handle does not exist anymore.